# Is there any script available which update phpMyadmin table data without reload the browser

Tags: phpmyadmin

Is there any script or settings available which will update phpmyadmin table data without reload the browser ?

I might insert data in a mysql table through terminal or html form and then the phpmyadmin will automatically the update the table without reload or refresh the browser.

Answer (score 1):

No, to show new data phpMyAdmin currently requires you to refresh the display (which does not require a "browser reload"; resubmitting a query or pressing the "Browse" link will do nicely).

I don't think it's very practical for large data sets to constantly push new rows back to the browser via AJAX or some other dynamic page display technique due to the risk of overloading the browser (or use) with rapid-fire amounts of new data.